# Android Bluetooth Connection Implement

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

My app can connect with a blutooth device and read data, but when the bluetooth is offline, my app will freeze the screen until it finds the device or timeout. Here are the main functions:

Manifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyGatewayService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

BluetoothManager.java

```
public class BluetoothManager {

        private static final String TAG = BluetoothManager.class.getName();
        private static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

        public static BluetoothSocket connect(BluetoothDevice dev) throws IOException{

            BluetoothSocket sock = null;
            BluetoothSocket socketFallback = null;
            Log.d(TAG,"Start Bluetooth Connection...");
            try
            {
                sock = dev.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
                Log.d(TAG, "Probably gonna wait here...");
                sock.connect();
            }catch (Exception e1){
                Log.e(TAG, "There was an error while establishing Bluetooth connection, Failing back...", e1);

            }
            return sock;
        }

    }
```

MyGateWayService.java

```
public class MyGatewayService extends AbstractGatewayService{
    private static final String TAG = MyGatewayService.class.getName();
    private BluetoothDevice dev = null;
    private BluetoothSocket sock = null;

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      //what should I put in here?
}

    @Override
    public void startService() throws IOException {
        final String remoteDevice = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_BLUETOOTH_SELECTION_ADDRESS_KEY, "");

        if (remoteDevice == null||"".equals(remoteDevice)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Bluetooth device selected...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG,"No Bluetooth device selected...");
            stopService();
            throw new IOException();
        }else{
            final BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            dev = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(remoteDevice);
            Log.d(TAG,"Stop bluetooth discovery...");
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.d(TAG,"Start Service..");
            try{
                startServiceConnection();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG, "There was an error while establishing connection..." + e.getMessage());



           stopService();
            throw new IOException();
        }
    }
}

    private void startServiceConnection() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Start the connection");
        isRunning = true;

        try{
            sock = com.ibm.us.wuxiaosh.androidbluetoothdemo.BluetoothManager.connect(dev);
        }catch (Exception e2){
            Log.e(TAG, "There was an error while connecting... stop...");
            stopService();
            throw new IOException();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void executeQueue(){
        Log.d(TAG,"Executing...");
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            //Log.d(TAG,"Executing ....................");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void stopService() {
        isRunning = false;

        if (sock!=null){
            try{
                sock.close();
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            stopSelf();
        }
    }
}
```

Mainfunction:

```
@Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
            Log.d(TAG, className.toString() + " service is bound");
            isServiceBound = true;
            service = ((AbstractGatewayService.AbstractGatewayServiceBinder) binder).getService();
            service.setContext(MainActivity.this);
            Log.d(TAG, "Starting live data");

            try{
                service.startService();

                Log.d(TAG , "Connected");


            } catch (IOException ioe){
                Log.e(TAG, "Failure Starting Live Data");
                doUnbindService();
            }

        }
        @Override
        protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
            return super.clone();
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            Log.d(TAG, " service is unbound");
            isServiceBound = false;
        }
    };




    private void doBindService(){
        if(!isServiceBound){
            Log.d(TAG, "Binding OBD Service..");

            Log.e(TAG,"start intent 1");
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyGatewayService.class);
            Log.e(TAG,"intent finished");
            bindService(serviceIntent,serviceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            Log.e(TAG,"bindService");
        }
    }

    private void doUnbindService(){
        if(isServiceBound){
            if (service.isRunning()){
                service.stopService();

                Log.d(TAG,"Ready");
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "Unbinding OBD Service...");
            unbindService(serviceConn);
            isServiceBound = false;
            Log.e(TAG, "Disconnected");
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**: 
another file: AbstractGateWayService  & changed it to extends intentService

```
public abstract class AbstractGatewayService extends IntentService{
    private static final String TAG = AbstractGatewayService.class.getName();
    private final IBinder binder = new AbstractGatewayServiceBinder();
    protected Context ctx;
    protected boolean isRunning = false;

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e(TAG, "Thread Run...");
                long futureTime = System.currentTimeMillis()+10000;
                while(System.currentTimeMillis()<futureTime) {
                    executeQueue();
                }
        }
    });

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "Creating Service...");
        t.start();
        Log.d(TAG, "Service Creating...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG,"Destroying service");
        t.interrupt();
        Log.d(TAG,"Service Destroyed");
    }

    class AbstractGatewayServiceBinder extends Binder {
        public AbstractGatewayService getService(){
            return AbstractGatewayService.this;
        }
    }
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }

    public void setContext(Context c) {
        ctx = c;
    }

    abstract protected void executeQueue();

    abstract public void startService() throws IOException;

    abstract public void stopService();
}
```

When I press the connect button, the app will initialize the service but it will also freeze the animation on the main thread, even if I explicitly put it in a separate thread. Based on the logcat I think the `sock.connect()` funtion in the `BluetoothManager.java` file is waiting for the callback. How should I implement to make sure everything runs in the background?

I also put all the code in [here](https://github.com/wilsonandusa/AndroidBluetoothDemo/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/ibm/us/wuxiaosh/androidbluetoothdemo)

Any help are welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you invoke the Socket connection logic (which, as you correctly deducted, is a blocking call) in the `startService()` method. `Services` in Android, while logically separate from the main flow of the app, run on the same `Thread` by default. By calling a blocking call in the service, you block the UI Thread.

You have several solutions to choose from:

- Use `IntentService` instead of `Service`. `IntentService` has its own Handler and operates on a separate Thread.
- Leave the logic in the current point, but wrap it in an `AsyncTask`. **IMPORTANT**: you need to wrap the logic itself, not the `Service`-starting logic.
- Drop the `Service` part altogether and just put the logic in an `AsyncTask`

It is up to you what you choose, the `IntentService` solution seems best for a more complex app, while creating an `AsyncTask` would be the quickest and most straight-forward approach :-)

Comment: Hi @Kelevandos Thanks for your reply, I think I will use the IntentService, I also updated my post to include my changes and added the abstract service class, since I've already implemented startService() method, should I move it into onHandleIntent? I want to know what should I put into the onHandleIntent method. Thank you

Comment: You could try moving all the logic there and checking if it will work. There is a lot of code in your examples so I can not say if it will without a broader context :-) Also, as for the IntentService setup, you may want to create and use a Handler with a Looper instead of a custom Thread.